# Printing failed test case names in Catch2

Tags: c++, catch2

I have a relatively huge number of test cases. In case of failure, it takes time to go through all the log files and find the failed test cases. Is there any way in Catch2 to print the failed test cases?

Comment: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/command-line.md#top

Comment: @Eljay There is currently no command-line option that shows the only failed or successful test cases' names at the end of the reporter.

Comment: @Emil • Aww, drat.  Sorry.  (I switched from [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) to [Doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) several years ago.  I like Catch2, and I like Doctest even better.  For my needs, either one works better for me than Boost Test or GoogleTest.)

Comment: Catch2 almost meets my needs, but at some point, simple features are lacking. Will try Doctest as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [EventListener](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/event-listeners.md) and override `testCaseEnded` to capture the names of the failed tests and `testRunEnded` to print them out.

```
struct EventListener : Catch::TestEventListenerBase
{
    using TestEventListenerBase::TestEventListenerBase;

    void testCaseEnded(Catch::TestCaseStats const& testCaseStats) final
    {
        if (testCaseStats.totals.assertions.failed > 0)
        {
            // store failed test
        }
    }

    void testRunEnded(Catch::TestRunStats const&) final
    {
        // print summary
    }
};

CATCH_REGISTER_LISTENER(EventListener)
```